# Find all possible combinations of dividers to match the sum condition

Tags: algorithms, combinations

I will give you an example what I'm looking for.

Let's assume that I have the following numbers defined at the beginning of an algortihm:

7, 10, 30, 60

I want to find all possible combinations of this numbers that will be greater or equal to 350. Order of numbers doesn't matter (I'm not looking for permutations).

Sample results:

50 * 7 = 350 >= 350 (OK)

49 * 7 + 10 = 343 + 10 = 353 > 353 (OK)

48 * 7 + 10 = 336 + 10 = 346 < 353 (NOT OK)

...and so on (to use also dividers 30 and 60)

I want to point out, that the correct result should be equal or grater to 350, but also should be as close to 350 as it is possible (each divider has its own price -> The total price should be to lowest).

How should I caluculate such combinations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is not clear.  is $10^{100}\times 7$ a valid combination?  Why not?  What about $30^{60}$?

Comment: So you also want ot include $99999\cdot 7+99999\cdot 10+99999999\cdot 30+9999\cdot 60$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, nobody can sort out what sort of combinations you want to count.

Comment: Yes! I can clarify the question. Correct combination is when the result is greater to 350 or it is as close as possible to 350.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything.  Look at the comments.  People have asked about specific combinations.  Please respond to those questions.

Comment: Maybe you want to find all x,y,z,t that Minimizes F such that F=7x+10y+30z+60t AND F<=350 with the condition that x,y,z and t are of values between 0 and 50.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the comment. I assume that the greatest number of dividers will be equal to the value 350/(the_value_of_the_lowest_divider) => 350/7 = 50. Now, I want to try to replace n nmber of  "7 dividers" with other dividers so that the sum of these divders should be still equal or greater to 350, but should be also as close to 350 as it is possible.

Comment: @NoChance yup, It looks like this is what I'm looking for. So I will have to implement a mechanism (probably with nested loops) to combinate all possible valus of x, y, z, t for a numbers between 1 and 50. Correct me if I'm wrong but the total numer of combinations will be 50^4. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is 51^4 since zero is included. If you need a program to do this, then I think you should re-formulate the question and post in stackoverflow. Having said that, some clever programming could reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: Cool! Definitely the missing part in my thinking was to formulate the  F=7x+10y+30z+60t function. Having this function defined, everything is much clear. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Good luck.